# Why does a string search for hex digits \x42 not find asterisk characters?

Tags: pandas, string, hex, contains

I have a data frame with a column containing both '#' and '*' characters:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id': [0, 1, 2, 3], 
        'foo': ["1#", "2*", "3#", "4*"]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

```
   id foo
0   0  1#
1   1  2*
2   2  3#
3   3  4*
```

If I search for '#' using hex digits \x23 from the ascii table it returns rows containing 1# and 3#:

```
print(df.loc[ df['foo'].str.contains('\x23') ])
```

```
   id foo
0   0  1#
2   2  3#
```

However, if I search for an asterisk using hex digits \x42 nothing is returned:

```
print(df.loc[ df['foo'].str.contains('\x42') ])
```

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, foo]
Index: []
```

I can instead use '*' to find the correct rows, but why does the hex digit search not find anything?

```
print(df.loc[ df['foo'].str.contains('\*') ])
```

```
   id foo
1   1  2*
3   3  4*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `*` in hex is `x2a`:

```
print (hex(ord('*')))
0x2a

print(df.loc[ df['foo'].str.contains(r'\x2a') ])
   id foo
1   1  2*
3   3  4*
```

And `hex` `42` is `B`:

```
data = {'id': [0, 1, 2, 3], 
        'foo': ["1#", "2*", "3B", "4*"]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.loc[ df['foo'].str.contains('\x42') ])
   id foo
2   2  3B

print (chr(int('0x42', 0)))
B
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I think I've confused the Decimal and Hex values in the ascii table. I had tried ('\x2A') but received an error 'nothing to repeat at position 0', which is because I hadn't used the 'r' in 'r\x2A'.